# if binary heap potential function is c*size(binary heap)) then insert will not take O(logn)and extract min will not take O(1) amortized time

Tags: amortized-analysis

So i want to prove that if i choose a potential function for binary heap as any **constant*size of the binary heap** (n is the number of nodes) then my insert will not have **O(logn)** amortized cost and extract Max will not have **O(1)** amortized cost.Insert and extract max have **O(logn)** as worst time complexity for binary heaps.

Let **ci** denotes real cost of i−th operation, and **ai** denotes amortized cost.

Let **Φ(Di)**=potential after i operations

INSERT:

```
                          ai= ci + Φ(Di) − Φ(Di−1)
                            = log(n) + c*n - c*(n-1)
                            = log(n) + c(n-n+1)
                            = log(n) + c
```

So im unsure as to how to prove that this potential function does not get **O(logn)** insert amortized cost. **O(logn)** would mean all functions that are less than or equal to **xlog(n)** (x is any constant).**log(n)+c** is greater than **log(n)** but is it less than **x(logn+c)**? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please take a moment to properly format your post.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The amortized running time of Insert and ExtractMax are whatever they are; they don't depend on the potential function you choose.  Perhaps you want to prove a lower bound on their amortized cost?  If so, you need to find a sequence of operations such that they cost at least (such-and-such).  Does this give you a different idea about a direction to try?

Comment: The question that im trying to solve states that  give a potential function Φ such that the amortized cost of INSERT is O(log n) and the amortized cost of EXTRACT MAX is O(1) with respect to Φ which i solved. The next part is asking me to prove that for any constant c, the potential function Φ(H) = c×size(H) is not a solution for the above conditions for insert and extract max.